Which limitations of the org.bson.Document do not allow multiple $or / $and expressions? Can we not fix that?
org.springframework.data.mongodb.InvalidMongoDbApiUsageException: 
Due to limitations of the org.bson.Document, you can't add a second '$or' 
expression specified as '$or: [Document{{active=false}}, 
Document{{active=null}}]'; Criteria already contains '$or: 
[Document{{payerId=Document{{$in=[64aeae270d0313320626dc55]}}}}, 
Document{{payerLoginId=Document{{$in=[64aeae270d0313320626dc55]}}}}]'

For the famous above issue there is a well-known workaround, instead of:
criteria.orOperator(Criteria.where(field).is(value), 
                    Criteria.where(field).is(anotherValue));
criteria.orOperator(Criteria.where(field2).is(value2), 
                    Criteria.where(field2).is(anotherValue2));

To chain the multiple $or within an $and:
criteria.andOperator(
new Criteria().orOperator(Criteria.where(field).is(value), 
                          Criteria.where(field).is(anotherValue)),
new Criteria().orOperator(Criteria.where(field2).is(value2), 
                          Criteria.where(field2).is(anotherValue2)));

Though my question is what limitation are we workarounding here? The mongodb itself can work well with:
{$or:[{field:"value"}, {field:"anotherValue"}], 
 $or:[{field2:"value2"}, {field2:"anotherValue2"}]}

UPDATE:
Thanks aneroid for pointing this out: multiple $orare not accepted by mongodb query syntax. Now my question would be towards MongoDB's team. Why $and is implicitly assumed when chaining multiple equality conditions, but not when chaining such $orones?

The query you've provided at the end has two $or clauses - { $or: [...], $or: [...] } - That does not work in MongoDB. Compass simply ignores one of the $or clauses and executes the query. Usually, the second $or overwrites the first. So what that actually executes is just { $or: [ {field2: "value2"}, {field2: "anotherValue2"} ] }.

wow, thanks @aneroid for the point. Let me double-check that. I did not assume Compass would trick me like this :)

Wrt "what limitation are we workarounding here?" - that depends on what you're trying to do. You want two fields to each have one of two values? Then it's { $and: [ <field1 options with $or>, <field2 options with $or>] }. It's logically sensible. "[Field1 must have ValueA or ValueB] AND [Field2 must have ValueX or ValueY]".

"I did not assume Compass would trick me like this" Compass is not tricking you :-) Some/several languages don't throw an error on such statements. For example, Python allows dictionaries (like hash maps) to contain two items which have the same key, it just overwrites with the last defined value. I think JS does the same thing. That's sort of the query format in Compass. See that error in Mongo Playground.

yes the $and: $or, $oris what I want, but since {field1: "v1", field2: "v2"} is implicitly doing an $and and is slick, I expected to be able to define the same with $or without the need of explicitly wrapping it within an $and

If you're just doing a find with static values and no other expressions and "slick", then use $in with both fields { field: { $in: [...] }, field2: { $in: [...] } }. Mongo Playground

yes, for this use case it would work, but mine is more sophisticated. I need the multiple $or and I am still wondering why mongodb team decided to imply an $and for some things and to forbid it for others

The reason a workaround is necessary is you are not building a BSON query directly.  The example code there builds a Java object, which will then be converted to BSON when submitted to the database server.
When you build a query like
criteria.orOperator(Criteria.where(field).is(value), 
                    Criteria.where(field).is(anotherValue));
criteria.orOperator(Criteria.where(field2).is(value2), 
                    Criteria.where(field2).is(anotherValue2));

that is essentially the same as the query:
{
  "$or":[{"field":value},{"field":anotherValue}],
  "$or":[{"field2":value2},{"field2":anotherValue2}]
}

Note that this is not a valid Java object as it has the same field name, $or twice.
The BSON spec does not explicitly prohibit duplicate field names in a document, but Java does:
Object properties are an instance of java.util.Dictionary, which specifies:

In any one Dictionary object, every key is associated with at most one value.

So it is not possible to build a Java object with 2 properties associated with different values, but both with the same name.
The workaround of wrapping the pair of $or clauses in an $and clause effectively moves them to an array where each $or is in a separate object:
{"$and":[
  {"$or":[{"field":value},{"field":anotherValue}]},
  {"$or":[{"field2":value2},{"field2":anotherValue2}]}
]}

This avoids the duplicate property name in a single object, while allowing the intended logic to be applied.
